# What are the differences between Action and Action.async

Tags: scala, playframework

I am confused between the usage of `Action` and `Action.async`. And what is the appropriate condition to use one.
I have wrote the method with `Action.async` with just a for loop, which takes 12 secs to process:

```
 def asyncIndex() = Action.async {
  val time = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)
  Future {
  for(i<- 0 to 20000000) {
      print(i)
    }
    Ok(Json.toJson(time))
   }
}
```

When I simultaneously make two request to this method the second request is blocked until the first one is completed.

PS:- I Think I have not understood the proper concept about async call.

Comment: There is no difference between `Action` and `Action.async`, every action is by default async, so behind the scene evrything is async, these days whatever you write is returing future, so just for chaining of that `Action.async` is there. give this link a try https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused in Action and Action.async and what is the appropriate condition to use one

From the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync#Actions-are-asynchronous-by-default):

> **Note**: Both `Action.apply` and `Action.async` create `Action` objects that are handled internally in the same way. There is a single kind of `Action`, which is asynchronous, and not two kinds (a synchronous one and an asynchronous one). The `.async` builder is just a facility to simplify creating actions based on APIs that return a `Future`, which makes it easier to write non-blocking code.

---

> when i simultaneously make two request to this method the second request is blocked until the first one is completed

Also from the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync#Creating-non-blocking-actions):

> The web client will be blocked while waiting for the response, but nothing will be blocked on the server, and server resources can be used to serve other clients.

If your simultaneous requests are from the same synchronous client, one of the requests *on the client side* will be blocked until the other is completed. There is no blocking on the server side. To achieve parallel processing of requests to the same endpoint, use distinct clients to make those requests, or use a client that makes asynchronous HTTP calls. Also consider using a separate dispatcher for this endpoint, even if you're wrapping the processing inside a `Future` (more information on creating a custom dispatcher is in the linked documentation).

Answer (score 0):

**Waiting blocks in code created that waiting time**: The code written with the body of `Future` is not fully concurrent because there is a loop in it before sending the `Ok` response; so obviously when you send the calls it takes some time to get the second response. If you remove the for loop and send number of calls (through `curl` for example) you will see the app is running without "awaiting" time. Of course this has the limitation; which is the specifications of your machine (cpu, ram, etc.). So, using `Action.async` just by itself and writing a waiting/blocking inside it; doesn't make the whole code concurrent.

**When to use**: There is simple rule for it: If your controller's method body has concurrent code in it then the action should be defined as `Action.async{...}`; if not `Action{...}`.

Please note that in Play [all actions are asynchronous](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAsync#Actions-are-asynchronous-by-default).